# Fuse ESB Transactions using JDBC and Queues

Tags: jdbc, transactions, jms, fuseesb

Is it possible to support the following scenario using Fuse ESB, JMS and JDBC?

From an orchestrating component I want to be able to:

1. start a transaction
2. send a message to a remote queue and have this participate in this transaction
3. have the message handler on the remote queue particiapte in this transaction using a JDBC connection within the same transaction
4. return synchronously to the orchestrating component and then do the same on another remote queue and message handler
5. return synchronously once again and either commit the two JDBC transactions or roll them back.

I'm guessing this is only possible using synchronous queues and will require XA transactions, but I'm really not sure of the mechanism for enlisting the queue and the jdbc connections in the original transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you're probably in for a world of hurt :)

I should say it is theoretically possible using a [Java Transaction Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_transaction_service). This is a bit different from your standard JTA transaction manager, and it uses [IIOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Inter-ORB_Protocol) to propagate transactional contexts to remote participants.

Take a look at [JBossJTS](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossJTS). It's not too hard to set up and reasonably well documented.

But for what you outlined, I strongly recommend you look for a better way to do this. It will be complicated and you will almost certainly wrestle with getting vendors (i.e. Resource Managers) to behave nicely with the transaction manager and each other.